# Using of Jdbc.getConnection() statement in google apps script

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have several functions in my script file, After publishing doGet function all other functions are called using the serverHandlers, And I have used the statements like below, My doubt is can we use this "var conn=Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dburl, user, pwd);" globally per script file instead of writing inside every function.

If Yes, Please provide a simple example to understand the concept of using it.

```
function doGet()
{
      var conn=Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dburl, user, pwd);
      .............
      .............
      .............
      conn.close();
}
function X()
{
      var conn=Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dburl, user, pwd);
      .............
      .............
      .............
      conn.close();
}
function Y()
{
      var conn=Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dburl, user, pwd);
      .............
      .............
      .............
      conn.close();
}
function Z()
{
      var conn=Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dburl, user, pwd);
      .............
      .............
      .............
      conn.close();
}
```

Tnx,
CL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create constants but not variables. 
In your example you cannot use constant as maintain the connection to the database always open will not be the best technical solution. I sugest you to create a function that handle your database connections.

For constants and global variables discussion check this thread:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps-script/services/y7lB5AKcic0

Regards,
Breno

Answer (score 0):

You can make a library function specific for your jdbc connection and call it from your other scripts.

```
function connect(domain, projectid, dbname, user, pwd) {

 var connString = "jdbc:google:rdbms://" + domain + ":" + projectid + ":" + dbname + "/mysql";
 return Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(connString, user, pwd);   

}
```

Than call the function in the main script like this.

```
var conn =  mysql.connect(domain, projectid, dbname, user, pwd);
```

And than use the conn like usual.

```
var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the connection once in the doGet() function and pass that connection around to other functions in your script.

Comment: I'm not sure about this scenario. Can you please show me a sample code which is very useful and easy to understand. Tnx, CL